# How to call on name attribute of option tags from controller

Tags: html, controller, laravel-5

In my blade, I have this

```
<select class="form-control" name="region_id_report"><option name="blank">No Region</option></select>
```

In my controller, I have this variable:

```
$regionidreport = $request->region_id_report;
```

which echoes `No Region`.

What do I do if I want to echo `blank` instead and not the word itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `<option>` to `<option value="blank">` instead of `<option name="blank">`

Comment: worked! thanks for the vote up as well. returning the favor :)